# How to solve ValueError: I/O operation on closed file in Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

#### Here is the error:

Exception in Tkinter callback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File
"C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Python27\Assignment 2\Anh Tran n9795847 Assignment 2.py", line 183, in button1_clicked
    a_html.write(website) ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

#### Here is the function for the button:

```
def button1_clicked():
print quantities_mice.get()

a_html.write(website)

a_html.close()

webbrowser.open_new_tab('invoice.html')
```

#### Create a confirmation button (the first button)

```
e_button_confirmation = Button(e_mart, text = 'Click here to print invoice', fg= 'black', command=button1_clicked)

e_button_confirmation.pack()
```

Comment: what about `a_html.open()` ?

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: I have tried both swaping 'a_html.close()' to 'a_html.open()' and adding an extra 'a_html.open()', thanks for your discussion anyway

Comment: What exactly is a_html? Are you opening a file using `a_html = open('somefile', 'w')`? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see `a_html` variable, maybe you used global var?

Suggest try local var like this:

```
def button1_clicked():
  print quantities_mice.get()
  # open file here
  a_html = open(file_name, 'w')
  a_html.write(website)

  a_html.close()

  webbrowser.open_new_tab('invoice.html')
```